# How much can I safely sleep without input buffer overflow?

Tags: python, linux, serial-port, sleep, pexpect

In a Python program, using pexpect, I am trying to sleep periodically, then read out (with 0 timeout) the bytes arrived so far, from the serial port.

```
child = fdpexpect.fdspawn(fd, maxread=5000, ...
...
while True:
  time.sleep(0.1)  # 0.1 second
  x = child.read_nonblocking(size=5000, timeout=0)
  ...
```

The serial line speed is so that only about 2304 bytes can arrive within 0.1 second, which is far less than 5000.
Is my code safe against input data loss, due to overflow in some buffer(s)?
If not, how could it be made safe?

Comment: Can you test this empirically?  Do you have a full-speed input driver you can use?

Comment: How long does the read take?  Is it possible to receive 2696 bytes (to fill the buffer) in between **sleep** calls?

Comment: Based on the docs for time.sleep (https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.sleep), you cannot guarantee that it will sleep for 0.1s or less time. Therefore there is always a chance that (in an overloaded system) the sleep call will actually 'sleep' for much longer.

Comment: You're misusing the API.  If the program was performing calculations, then concern about overrun is a sensible question.  But to simply sleep before performing a non-blocking read (i.e. poll the buffers) indicates bad design.